# Safari 5.1 text-overflow ellipsis with SVG font not working

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, font-face

I have a `div` with `text-overflow:ellipsis` and `font-family:'SomeSvgFont'`.
The text wrapping works ok in all browsers except from Safari 5.1, where instead of `example@gmai...` the div displays `...`.

This doesn't happen if the font is, for example, of the woff type, but I prefer to use svg for its better font smoothing in webkit browsers (including Safari).

I've tested on Safari 5.1 on both Windows and OS X (later Safari versions on Mac works just fine).

Are there any workarounds to this problem?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YqdW/3/), and the complete code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AsapRegular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('url_to_my_svg_font') format('svg');
}

.wrap {
    font-family: 'AsapRegular', sans-serif;
    width: 6em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


<div class="wrap">example@gmail.com</div>
```

Comment: Do you have to support an N-2 version of a browser? Saf6 has been around for a while. Especially on Windows: who still uses Safari except webdevelopers? It was convenient for testing back when Apple cared to have both versions but nowadays?

Comment: Thanks @FelipeAls. I know Safari 5.1 is rare, but unfortunately it is still used by some of our customers. I probably won't invest too much time solving this, but if there's a quick workaround it will be nice to know about.

Answer (score 0):

This issue also occurs on chrome windows. My issue was solved by turning off text-rendering:optimizelegibility.